# Is there a fast way to get rows from a table by range as IQueryable in C# LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, repository, iqueryable

like say I want to make a method in my repository like

```
public IQueryable<Item> GetAllItemsByRange(int start, int end)
```

and then I just want to pass like (1, 100), (101, 200), (201, 300), etc so I can get back ONLY that range without having to get EVERYTHING at once

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
queryable.Skip(start - 1).Take(end - start + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

orderby is the key, then you can use skip(100).take(100) to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

return (from t in table
        select t).Skip(start).Take(end - start);